# Link path from array back to values echoed from readdir

Tags: php, json

I'm very new to php and json. I'm attempting to read in files from an array of directories, and echo out the files.

```
paths([
    "/assets/html/",
    "/assets/media/images/",
    "/assets/media/videos/"
]);

function paths($dir = []) {
    foreach($dir as $value) {
        if ($handle = opendir($value)) {
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                    echo $entry . "\n";
                    //echo json_encode($entry);
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, and returns a set of results that looks like:

```
Acephale.html
brain-apr-2011-pdf.jpg
brain-apr-2011-web.jpg
bdg_arch.mp4
...
```

What I'd like to do however, is echo out the specific path prior to the file found within - so the results would look like:

```
/assets/html/Acephale.html
/assets/media/images/brain-apr-2011-pdf.jpg
/assets/media/images/brain-apr-2011-web.jpg
/assets/media/videos/bdg_arch.mp4
...
```

Ultimately I would like to parse each result and encode it as json so that I end up with something like:

```
{"path":"/assets/html/","filename":"Acephale.html"},
{"path":"/assets/media/images/","filename":"brain-apr-2011-pdf.jpg"},
{"path":"/assets/media/images/","filename":"brain-apr-2011-web.jpg"},
{"path":"/assets/media/videos/","filename":"bdg_arch.mp4"},
...
```

Any tips/examples demonstrating either part (relinking the dirs and/or json encoding) would be really appreciated.

Comment: So, you have your path in `$value` for each iteration and your filename is in `$entry`. All that remains is to define an array at the beginning of the function where you will add this information and ultimately return a [JSON encoded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) version of it.

Comment: Or you could have your function return the array, then you can either loop and echo from it or JSON encode it or whatever you might wish to do with this information in the future.

Comment: Ugh. Thank you. I had it the whole time right in front of me, I just didn't grok the syntax, all I needed to do for the first part was add the value `echo $value . $entry . "\n";`

Answer (score 2):

json_encode converts associative arrays in javascript plain objects. This means that if you need an object with a property called "path" and other called "filename" you must to create an associative array with these indexes in php. More about json_encode [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Example

```
<?php

$data = [
   'path' => '/some/path',
   'filename' => 'some-filename'
];

json_encode($data); // produces {"path": "/some/path", "filename": "some-filename"}
```

Said that, let me share you some suggestions.

1. Is very important separate concepts because you focus in little problems.
2. create a function to get all files for a directory
3. create a function to generate the final data structure
4. encode the formatted data as json

```
<?php

// create a function to get all files for a directory
function getDirectoryFiles($path) {
    $files = scandir($path);
    $filesCleaned = [];

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $filesCleaned[] = $file;
        }
    }

    return $filesCleaned;
}

// create a function to generate the final data structure
function getPathAndFilesArrayInOneDimmension($paths) {
    $final = [];

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        foreach (getDirectoryFiles($path) as $filename) {
            // each item of final output is a simple object with two properties: path and filename
            $final[] = [
                'path' => $path,
                'filename' => $filename,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $final;
}

// encode the formatted data as json
$paths = [
    "/assets/html/",
    "/assets/media/images/",
    "/assets/media/videos/"
];

$data = getPathAndFilesArrayInOneDimmension($paths);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear and concise explanation, and the working code sample. Much appreciated!